# How do I do a many-to-many relationship in LINQ?

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

I have two tables say, t1 and t2 that have t1.t1_id and t2.t2_id as primary keys.  They are related by table t3 with columns t3.t1_id and t3.t2_id, respectively.  Using LINQ I get an EntitySet<t3> on class t1 and t2, but what I want is an EntitySet<t2> on class t1 and EntitySet<t1> on class t2.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

[From Mitsu's Blog on MSDN](http://blogs.msdn.com/mitsu/archive/2007/06/21/how-to-implement-a-many-to-many-relationship-using-linq-to-sql.aspx)

Update:
I forgot to link part 2 of the blog entry:
[Second Part](http://blogs.msdn.com/mitsu/archive/2008/03/19/how-to-implement-a-many-to-many-relationship-using-linq-to-sql-part-ii-add-remove-support.aspx)